# How would you examine samples of rocks using a handheld spectrometer?

Tags: spectroscopy, mass-spectrometry

My friend has an old spectrometer set that his father used to own and we are trying to figure out how to use it. Asking his father about it is not an option unfortunately.

The box contains a handheld spectrometer. It is cylindrical in shape, length around 10 cm and diameter around 1 cm. There is a lens at both ends. We can't see through it.

In the box there are around 10 samples of different rocks. They are around the size of a golf ball but irregular in shape.

There is nothing else in the box. We presume there are components missing.

Is there some way to analyse these rocks with the spectroscope ?

Maybe I need to shine a laser or light on the rocks in some particular way, or grind a sample of the rock into dust and put it through a flame.

All suggestions welcome.

Comment: You may add a photo of the device to substantiate your question.  And don't shine with a laser on the samples in front of the spectrometer, your eyes may be damaged beyond repair by this.

Comment: You might have a gem's testing spectroscope. https://lotusgemology.com/index.php/library/articles/282-gem-testing-with-the-spectroscope-lotus-gemology